# Progressbar using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the HTML i use:

```
<progress id="amount" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

This is the JavaScript i use:

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () { // this is 8 minutes progressbar
        var t = Math.floor((i / 240) * 100);
        $('#amount').attr('value', t);
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the value directly jumps to 100% the first second.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize that `for` sets your timer each time increasing its speed, yeah? And does it very fast, you even can't notice.
Actually there is no need in it, your timer is already used to loop. Remove it.

```
<script>
     var i = 0;
     var timer = setInterval(function () { // this is 8 minutes progress bar
        if(i<240) { 
            i++;
            var t = Math.floor((i / 240) * 100);
            $('#amount').attr('value', t);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer=null;
        }
    }, 2000);

</script>
```

Comment: everything working great thanks  except progress ends in 96 seconds i can use unitary method for 8 mins , but i guess if you can help to figure out the problem.

Comment: @php_to_android replace 2000 with 10000. Will be slower.

Comment: i know,ok how can i get exact 8 minutes wait?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting all 240 setTimeouts at the very beginning, so they all run 2 seconds after the page loads. (The for loop won't wait for each one to run before setting the next one, because you haven't told it to).

Try something like this, where you only set the following `setTimeout` once the previous one has occurred.

```
var i = 0;

function tick() {
    var t = Math.floor((i / 240) * 100);
    $('#amount').attr('value', t);

    if (i < 240) {
        i++;
        setTimeout(tick, 2000); // set the next progression of the bar for 2 seconds after this one
    }
};

tick(); // do the first progression of the bar
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhsP8/2/

Comment: everything working great thanks except progress ends in 96 seconds i can use unitary method for 8 mins , but i guess if you can help to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure to do this. Two ways:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (x) {
        return function () {
            $('#amount').prop('value', Math.floor((x / 240) * 100));
        }
    }(i), 2000*i);
}
```

or

```
var func = function (i) {
    return function () {
        $('#amount').prop('value', Math.floor((i / 240) * 100));
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
    setTimeout(func(i), 2000 * i);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8RuNH/)**

Answer (score -2):

The api for the jquery progressbar is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) An example of it can be seen [here](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

Here is some sample code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 37
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"></div>


</body>
</html>
```